# Apache Hadoop Yarn - Underutilization of cores

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

No matter how much I tinker with the settings in `yarn-site.xml` i.e using all of the below options

```
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores
```

i just still cannot get my application i.e Spark to utilize all the cores on the cluster. The spark executors seem to be correctly taking up all the available memory, but each executor just keeps taking a single core and no more.

Here are the options configured in `spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.executor.cores                    3
spark.executor.memory                   5100m
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead      800
spark.driver.memory                     2g
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead        400
spark.executor.instances                28
spark.reducer.maxMbInFlight             120
spark.shuffle.file.buffer.kb            200
```

Notice that `spark.executor.cores` is set to 3, but it doesn't work.
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The problem lies not with `yarn-site.xml` or `spark-defaults.conf` but actually with the resource calculator that assigns the cores to the executors or in the case of MapReduce jobs, to the Mappers/Reducers.

The default resource calculator i.e `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator` uses only memory information for allocating containers and CPU scheduling is not enabled by default. To use both memory as well as the CPU, the resource calculator needs to be changed to `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator` in the `capacity-scheduler.xml` file.

Here's what needs to change.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
</property>
```

Comment: well, stackoverflow encourages you to share one's knowledge, so doing just that :)

Comment: good work - I just went through a whole lot of trouble finding out exactly the same, including filing a bug with yarn (it is not a bug). Just wish I found this earlier. See [official Hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html). Careful when copy-pasting, I also found out that the original documentation misspelt `Resource` as `Resourse` within the configuration (s vs c).

Comment: for me over utilisation of cpu is coming for mapreduce job... only 2 cores configured,but load avarage for mapreduce is high.. some time a hike in cpu % is also there.. any idea?

Comment: But does it really uses only one core per executor? Or it is just the calculation for the number of executors? I mean, does --executor-cores value still work when using the DefaultResourceCalculator?

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar kind of issue and from my code i was setting up the `spark.executor.cores as 5`.
Even though it was just taking 1 which is the default core. In the spark UI and in environment tab i was seeing 5 cores. But while checking the executors tabs i was just able to see 1 process is in **RUNNING** state against an executor.
I was using the spark version **1.6.3**.

So then i have tried to hit the spark-submit command as 
`--conf spark.executor.cores=5` which is working fine as using 5 cores

or just

`--executor-cores 5` which also works.