# What is the difference between spark.executor.cores and executor-cores in the spark-submit command?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there any difference between `executor-cores` and `spark.executor.cores` used in spark-submit command?

My job is failed because of GC overhead memory error, so i am trying to increase cores and memory settings.

The total volume i am processing is 50 M records in two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `executor-cores` flag used in the `spark-submit` command simply set the `spark.executor.cores` setting on the Spark-configuration. So they have the same effect :)

A couple of things you may try:

1) You have tagged the question with YARN, so if you find that you are not utilizing all of your cores, you should have a look at [Apache Hadoop Yarn - Underutilization of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964792/apache-hadoop-yarn-underutilization-of-cores)

2) Many memory issues on YARN are solved when you increase the memory-overhead by explicitly setting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead. It will default to `max(386MB, 0.10* executorMemory)` and that is frequently not enough.