# spark-submit not getting resources as submmited?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

1. **Summary**: I am using `spark-submit` to submit my application to my spark cluster but the resource allocated to my application is not aligned with the parameters I specified.
2. **Details**: I am always getting 4 containers and 16 cores and 74752MB RAM(roughly 73G). And when I change `client` mode to `cluster`, I only got less, e.g. 9 containers 9 cores and 45056MB RAM(roughly 44GB). I find this information on the `cluster:8088` page where application info are shown. I also cross-reference with the executors tab of `spark:4044` where executors info are shown for spark application.
3. Below is the code snippet I use:
   `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --class "$1" target/scala-2.10/recommend-assembly-0.1.jar --executor-cores 8 --num-executor 15 --driver-memory 19g`
4. **Environment Info**: Spark1.6 on yarn, Hadoop2.6. A cluster of 4 Nodes(1 being master), each with 16-core CPU and 64GB RAM(even though my node somehow only has access to 40GB RAM each).
5. What I tried:

   1. I tried tinkering with the aforementioned paramters(e.g. num-executor), I am still getting the same amount of resource. But when I change `client` to `cluster`, the resources allocated is even less.
   2. I am suspecting that some setting of yarn is causing this. And I find [Apache Hadoop Yarn - Underutilization of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964792/apache-hadoop-yarn-underutilization-of-cores), however, it doesn't help after I change the setting in `capacity-scheduler.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take knowledge about spark on yarn,include container,stage,AM etc

Comment: Actually, I have read and searched through a lot of material. Guess I am too dumb to figure out this problem.