# How to parse Yarn logs to obtain performance indicators?

Tags: parsing, logging, hadoop-yarn

Summary: I need something to `yarn logs -applicationId myID  | parse`.

I am developing a code with some level of parallelism, so I need a feedback about *vcores* and RAM memory  used... I have the application ID of each test, so, after run I can use

```
 yarn logs -applicationId application_1581298836342_95477 > myYarnLog.txt
```

but it is a big and complex log, and I need only to check *vcores* and memory used.

There are a parse for `myYarnLog.txt`, that filter or calculate the performance indicators?

---

PS: "RAM memory" can be "Aggregate Resource Allocation", *vcores* can be some virtual-CPU allocation statistics, etc.

Comment: You can filter your text file: https://www.tecmint.com/linux-file-operations-commands/

Comment: Before writing it to file you can pipe into grep `| grep vcores` to get only the lines containing `vcores`.

Comment: Hi  @TinNguyen and VincenzoNinni, see [my Wiki-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514844/287948), you can edit there.

Answer (score 1):

in you yarn site.xml similar to, like [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/better-slas-via-resource-preemption-in-yarns-capacityscheduler/)

```
 yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable
```

you need silimar in file capacity-scheduler.xml as response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964792/apache-hadoop-yarn-underutilization-of-cores)

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Hi @Soleil, thanks the clues about the configuration. My need (the scope of the question) is about *"how to read the log-file"* of an executed script, **not** about the configuration. I need the fact, not the plan: the log-file say how many vcores, hours of vcores and RAM did the process really used.

Comment: sorry, maybe you need install a tool like http://lnav.org/features

Answer (score 0):

As @TinNguyen suggested, we can used `grep` to check some information, like the "vcores" lines... Perhaps other readers can suggest other grep strategies. So, **this answer is a Wiki** to consolidate all suggestions

---

All parsing suggestions are parsing the `myYarnLog.txt` file of the question,

```
 yarn logs -applicationId application_1581298836342_95477 > myYarnLog.txt
```

### Command and plugins suggestions

- `ag`. Key filter. Example: `ag vcores myYarnLog.txt`.
- `grep`. Key filter. Example: `grep -i vcores myYarnLog.txt`.
- `awk`. Turing-complete filter and formater. 
  Example: `awk "/vcores/i {print $0}" myYarnLog.txt`
- `lnav`, the "Log-file Navigator", http://lnav.org/features ([git](https://github.com/tstack/lnav)). 
  Accepts regex-filtering and others.

### Key suggestions

Key-words to filter relevant information for performance analysis.

Standard log terms:

- **LogAggregationType**.  Log-file standard attribute. Example: AGGREGATED.
- **INFO CodeGenerator**. Example: "Code generated in 381.632282 ms"
- **INFO MemoryStore**.Example: "Block broadcast_13_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 11.5 KB, free 37.2 GB)"
- **INFO TorrentBroadcast**. Example: "Reading broadcast variable 13 took 91 ms"
- ...

Generic terms, used in some logs:

- **vcore**. A term, *virtual-cores*, that can be used as unit. Examples: "4 vcores" or "5 seconds per vcore".
- **stored as bytes in memory**. Example: a line with no tag, say "Block broadcast_13 stored as values in memory (estimated size 26.3 KB, free 37.2 GB)"
- **bytes result sent to driver**. Is relevant?
- ...

Spark-specific key-words:

- **ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator**. Lines with started/getting times and blocks, useful for `awk` summarizations.
- ...

### Filtering rules

... use of columns,  composite filters, calculate totals, etc.

Example of awk rule: `/LogAggregationType/ {print "log type: " $2}`.

---

### Evidence-based tuning of config

In any [evidence-based practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence-based_practice) we need data to analyse and act... In this case the data of the log-file, to do good changes in the config-file.

[image: evidence-based cycle]

See [how to change config files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29964793/287948) on Yarn, Spark, etc.