# Spark reads in parallel but writes partitions with only one core

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-iceberg

I have a 300 GB csv file that I am writing to an existing iceberg table using a local Spark cluster. My context is initialized like this:

```
.master("local[*]") \
.config("spark.driver.memory", "30g") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "15g") \
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.catalog.my_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO") \
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload", "true") \
```

After the transformations, I create a `partition_key` so that my dataframe is split into roughly equal sized partitions.  File sizes in S3 end up being ~ 200 MB.  During the first stage of execution (reading, application of the schema, transformations, and partitioning) Spark works very fast, completing 2470 tasks in 20 minutes, with 300 GB input, 50 GB shuffle write, and uses all 10 local cores.

However, as soon as the second stage starts (the actual writing to S3), Spark writes using only *one* core (note: this is not throttled by internet connection).

```
df.repartition("partition_key") \
    .write \
    .format("iceberg") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("path", "s3://my_bucket/my_db/") \
    .partitionBy(["partition_key"]) \
    .saveAsTable("glue_catalog.my_db.data")
```

I have read that because I am using a local Spark instance, I have virtually only one executor (my local jvm instance), which throttles writing.  However, that doesn't make sense because it does not throttle reading (which uses all cores in parallel). How can writing partitions be sped up and parallelized?

I tried adding dynamic allocation but this did not help:

```
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
```

Is there a reason that read parallelization happens by default in Spark whereas write parallelization with partitions does not?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use `"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"` as it tries to allocate everything to one executor based on `default resource calculator.`

More details in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29964793/3238085

Set the executor size on the commandline. You might need to finetune the following settings. You can look at your cores utilization in Yarn Resource Manager UI.

```
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--num-executors 4 \
--executor-memory 1G \
--executor-cores 1 \
--driver-memory 2G \
--driver-cores 1 \
```

Check the number of executors and tasks in the `Spark Histor Server UI` when the writing operation starts.

Another thing I might suggest is to increase the number of parallelism in AWS CLI config.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html

```
These are the configuration values you can set specifically for the aws s3 command set:

max_concurrent_requests - The maximum number of concurrent requests.
max_queue_size - The maximum number of tasks in the task queue.
multipart_threshold - The size threshold the CLI uses for multipart transfers of individual files.
multipart_chunksize - When using multipart transfers, this is the chunk size that the CLI uses for multipart transfers of individual files.
max_bandwidth - The maximum bandwidth that will be consumed for uploading and downloading data to and from Amazon S3.
```

Comment: Thank you - is it possible in local mode without using yarn ?

Comment: should be possible. `http://localhost:4040` This provides spark history UI.